# How do I translate SUMIFS statements from Excel to Access?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I currently have this SUMIFS statement in Excel:

```
=SUMIFS( ORDERS!$I:$I,ORDERS!$D:$D, C4,  ORDERS!$G:$G, "Change", ORDERS!$L:$L, "")
```

The first criterion is to match the identifier in cell C4 to the identifier located in "Orders". The second criterion is to ensure that the type was "Change". The third criterion is to ensure that I haven't flagged the order as excludable.

The two sheets I have are an order data sheet and a customer sheet.

My ultimate goal is to sum what is in column I for the many types of orders, based on the aforementioned first and third criteria. Currently in Excel I switch out the second criteria based on what order type I am summing.

I've transferred the data over to Access from Excel (there were a million rows and Excel was crashing even after I pasted values).

How do I structure a query to accomplish what the SUMIFS statement accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select sum(valueColumn) as theTotal 
from tableName 
where colA="someValue" 
and colB=5 
and colC is null
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible transition of sumifs from excel into Access !

```
select sum(Iif(colA="someValue"  and colB=5 and colC is null,valueColumn,0)) 
from mytable
```